# Is it possible to destroy a typhoon by bombs?

Tags: atmospheric-science, estimation, explosions, weather

When a typhoon is still on the ocean, if a big bomb or several bombs are thrown to it, maybe at the eye, or at the part where the wind circles fastest, can the bomb destroy the typhoon?

Comment: Why the down votes? It's a pretty interesting question, and an instance of the more general question: how stable are vortices against external perturbations? Seems to be a topic of current interest: see, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.02815 and https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-011-0249-0_8

Comment: https://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/tcfaq/C5c.html

Comment: @Loong Nice link! "According to the 1993 World Almanac, the entire human race used energy at a rate of 1013 watts in 1990, a rate less than 20% of the power of a hurricane." Wowzers. I'm making that my new suggestion for green energy.

Comment: @Loong energy consumption is not the same thing as the energy to destroy a target. A brick on the road could throw an F1 car off balance.

Comment: @RubenVerresen Another link: [Can we capture energy from a hurricane?](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/innovation/can-we-capture-energy-hurricane-180960750)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would just be a waste of money. The natural forces that fuel a typhoon, which absorbs energy from solar heated oceans, dwarf ordinary bombs into insignificance and are comparable but superior to the most powerful H-bombs ever tested (15 - 50 megatons). There is, of course, no question of dropping an exceptionally powerful H-bomb on a typhoon, that would only make things worse. As proof that typhoons derive their power from solar heated oceans, you need only observe their behaviour when they reach landfall. Their power rapidly dwindles away.

Comment: a bit disappointed..